# multi query select using wrong array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a multi query select which half works. The first query is straight forward.

```
$sql = "SELECT riskAudDate, riskClientId, RiskNewId FROM tblriskregister ORDER BY riskId DESC LIMIT 1;";
```

The second one doesn't seem to work even when I do it on its own:

```
$sql ="SELECT LAST(riskFacility) FROM tbleClients";
```

If I get rid of the LAST it returns the first entry in that field of the table. I want to use the LAST to get the LAST entry in that field.

When I do the first query on its own I get the data returned and I can echo it to the screen. When I add the second  (with out the LAST) I get nothing. Here is what I am using

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);      
if ($result == TRUE){     
    $r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $r['riskAudDate']; 
    echo $r['riskClientId'];
    echo $r['RiskNewId'];
    echo $r['riskFacility'];
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($r);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

The last bit is just for me to see whats in the array and just for testing.
So I have worked out that its the results array that is not right. 
If I change the actual query to multi query I get this:

```
Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean
```

So the array bit seems to be wrong for a multi query. The data returned is one row from each table. It works for the top query but add in the second (which I'm not sure is correct anyway) and the whole things crashes. So I guess it's a two part question. Whats wrong with my inserts and whats wrong with my returned array?

Comment: What "multiquery"? You're trying to execute two selects at once and get a result from that?

Comment: `fetch_array` returns `null` if there are no results.

Comment: sorry I had removed things to test them individually here is the proper one:      $sql = "SELECT riskAudDate, riskClientId, RiskNewId FROM tblriskregister ORDER BY riskId DESC LIMIT 1;";
$sql .="SELECT riskFacility FROM tbleClients";

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no `last()` function in mysql, it is only supported in ms access, if I'm not much mistaken. In mysql you can do what you do in the 1st query: do an order by and limit the results to 1.
2. According to the error message, the `$conn->query($sql)` returns a boolean value (probably true), therefore you cannot call `$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` on it. Since we have no idea what exactly you have in $sql variable, al I can say is that you need to debug your code to detrmine why `$conn->query($sql)` returns a boolean value.
3. Although it is not that clear from mysqli_query()'s documentation, but it only supports the execution of 1 query at a time. To execute multiple queries in one go, use [mysqli_multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) (you can call this one in OO mode as well, see documentation). However, for security reasons I would rather call mysqli_query() twice separately. It is more difficult to execute a successful sql injection attack, if you cannot execute multiple queries.

Comment: This is whats returned from the multi query '$sql  SELECT riskAudDate, riskClientId, RiskNewId FROM tblriskregister ORDER BY riskId DESC LIMIT 1;SELECT riskFacility FROM tbleClients ORDER BY riskFacility DESC LIMIT 1'

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what your comment means.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are trying to do two SQL-queries at once. 
That is not possible. Do a separate

```
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
if ($result == TRUE){     
    while( $r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        ...
    } 
}
```

for each SQL-query.

concerning :

```
$sql ="SELECT LAST(riskFacility) FROM tbleClients";
```

since the last function does not exists in MySQL i would recommend doing a sort like this(because i don't know what you mean with last )

```
$sql ="SELECT riskFacility FROM tbleClients order by riskFacility desc limit 0,1";
```

Comment: the mysql manual says you can do it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.html   And thanks I have used the sort to get the record I want.

Comment: yes, but it uses ->multi_query($sql) and ->store_result() and then ->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)  that is a different approach. if you like i can restructure my answer to that

Comment: ok we have progress.  I am using multi query and getting the results that I want back. I am using var_export to print to the screen what is being returned.  This is what Ive got:                                                                                           '( 0 => array ( 'riskAudDate' => '18-04-2016', 'riskClientId' => 'bob down', 'RiskNewId' => '1', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'riskFacility' => 'jjjjj', ), )'   I now need to get riskClient, RiskNewId and riskFacility out of the array as variables so I can use them.  Its here I have come unstuck.

Comment: probably like this: $riskClientId=$whatevervar[0][0]['riskClientId'];

Comment: thanks @snitch182  but I still think Im a few steps away from being able to retrieve anything.  For clarity here is the code Im using now.  Im using var_dump to see whats being returned and it is the information Im after.  It is two arrays.  One for the first query and another for the second.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT riskAudDate, riskClientId, RiskNewId FROM tblriskregister ORDER BY riskId DESC LIMIT 1;";
$sql .="SELECT riskFacility FROM tbleClients ORDER BY riskId DESC LIMIT 1";
  if (!$conn->multi_query($sql)) {
    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
 do {
    if ($res = $conn->store_result()) {
       var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
                $res->free();
                        }
}
 while ($conn->more_results() && $conn->next_result());'

Comment: If I change var_dump to   $var= var_export it only returns the last array.  I have spent hours researching how to get it to show both arrays but every example Ive come across is for a single query and no matter how Ive rejigged the code I just having stumbled across the right way to do it.

Comment: do $var[]=$res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); and it should put everying in $var ... in $var[0] for the first query $var[1] for the second query and so forth. If you are still having problems after that you should  ask another question with your current code attached. Or append your current question. I am 8 hours available from now.

Comment: Im going to put this on the backburner. I spent way to much time on trying to get it right when with two separate operations I was done.  I will try you latest suggestion as soon as I find some quiet time.  Ill let you know how I get on.